# Peugeot 307 horn not working

Tags: peugeot, horn

I own a Peugeot 307 , 2003 model . 97000 miles.

My local mechanic fixed its horn two times but after few weeks again it stopped working .

Now my MOT is due and was wondering what would be the best way to fix this ?

Should I go to Peugeot dealer ?

Comment: what did the mechanic fix when you took it to the workshop in the past two times?

Comment: He didn't say anything technical. It was  fixed as part of the check up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can check on your own, then check the following

1. Fuse(s) for horn (check if they are not blown)
2. Horn relay (check if you can hear the relay getting actuated when you press the horn)
3. If horn relay is working fine, then you need to check the wiring from the relay to horn and if that is ok, check the horns
4. If relay is not getting actuated, then there should be some issues with the horn switch, clock spring contact in the steering wheel or the wiring from the steering wheel to the relay

Comment: thank you . This will help me ask right questions from him this time .